# How to Connect a Spark Context to Multiple Mongo Collections? (SCALA)

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOCSZ.png)

This is important I just need to understand how to allow the Spark Context to read more than 1 Collection from the MongoDB database. It works when I imput only 1 Collection but then when I created the List I recieved an overflow error. I am new to coding and I'm not sure where to go from here so any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more details in your question. What's the stack trace for the error?

Comment: Hi Jevon! Welcome :) It would help users in answering your question if you could include the code in the question. There's [a page here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for guidance on formatting your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.